# mysql - run multiple queries in single query using different aliases

Tags: mysql

I have these 3 queries:

```
SELECT sum(sales) AS salesTotal FROM reporting WHERE date = '2023-01-10';
SELECT sum(traffic) AS trafficTotal FROM reporting WHERE date = '2023-02-15';
SELECT sum(transaction) AS transactionTotal FROM reporting WHERE date = '2023-03-05';
```

Now I want to run these 3 queries in a single query with aliases.

E.g what I was trying is:

```
TotalSalesValue AS SELECT sum(sales) AS salesTotal FROM reporting WHERE date = '2023-01-10',
TotalTrafficValue AS SELECT sum(traffic) AS trafficTotal FROM reporting WHERE date = '2023-02-15',
TotalTransactionValue AS SELECT sum(transaction) AS transactionTotal FROM reporting WHERE date = '2023-03-05';
```

I tried above query but it is giving me syntax error saying:

```
ER_PARSE_ERROR: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'TotalSalesValue AS SELECT
```

What I am expecting in return is something like this:

```
{
    "TotalSalesValue": 200,
    "TotalTrafficValue": 150,
    "TotalTransactionValue": 10
}
```

Can anyone help me with the correct syntax?

Comment: 'The response could be in array or any form.' - sql does not do arrays..

Comment: Yes so it could be in any form, also in columns

Comment: Your first set of queries uses aliases correctly , do you want 1 row with three columns or 1 column with 3 rows or possibly json output.?

Comment: @P.Salmon any way is fine.

Comment: For what it's worth, I'm quite good with SQL but I would do this as three separate queries. I don't see any value in combining them; it only makes the query more difficult to develop.

Comment: @BillKarwin so you would open up 3 db connections here? doesnt seem good idea

Comment: No need for three db connections. Just run one query after the other on the same connection.

Comment: Are you opening a new connection for every query? That would be unusual.

Answer (score 2):

Use conditional aggregation:

```
SELECT SUM(CASE WHEN date = '2023-01-10' THEN sales ELSE 0 END) AS TotalSalesValue, 
       SUM(CASE WHEN date = '2023-02-15' THEN traffic ELSE 0 END) AS TotalTrafficValue,
       SUM(CASE WHEN date = '2023-03-05' THEN transaction ELSE 0 END) AS TotalTransactionValue
FROM reporting;
```

If the table is large you could filter before the aggregation with:

```
WHERE date IN ('2023-01-10', '2023-02-15', '2023-03-05')
```

If you want the result as JSON:

```
SELECT json_object(
         'TotalSalesValue', SUM(CASE WHEN date = '2023-01-10' THEN sales ELSE 0 END), 
         'TotalTrafficValue', SUM(CASE WHEN date = '2023-02-15' THEN traffic ELSE 0 END),
         'TotalTransactionValue', SUM(CASE WHEN date = '2023-03-05' THEN transaction ELSE 0 END)
       ) AS result
FROM reporting;
```

Comment: You can even add a bit more to make this into a json format using the json functions. Anyways, up for the simplicity :)

Comment: @JorgeCampos of course. I added the query for a result as json.